# Bad starting token in AWS CLI for listing hosted zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

From within my EC2 instance, I run `aws route53 list-hosted-zones` and it successfully displays a list of hosted zones:

```
HOSTEDZONES 12345678-EEEE-7777-BBBB-ABCDEF123456    /hostedzone/Z1234567890XYZ  example.com.     9
CONFIG  Internal DNS    True
HOSTEDZONES 87654321-AAAA-9999-CCCC-ABCDEF987654    /hostedzone/Z1234567890ABC  example.org.    2
CONFIG  Staging True
```

But when I run the command to filter specific zones like `aws route53 list-hosted-zones --starting-token Z1234567890ABC`, it gives me:

```
Bad starting token: Z1234567890ABC
```

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-hosted-zones.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--starting-token` option doesn't take a zone ID.  It's for pagination only.  (Run `aws route53 list-hosted-zones help` for options.)

If you want to show the resource records for a specific zone, use `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <ZONE ID>`.  If you just want to show the information for a single zone, use `aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id <ZONE ID>`.

Comment: I see. The `--starting-token` takes in the value of `NEXTTOKEN` returned from paginated listing of zones. Thanks :)